# Identify similar names eg: "AAA BBB CCC" and "BBB AAA CCC" are the same people

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, vba

I am currently working on a problem. I have a column of Names. Below is the scenario

```
Anna Smith
Anna.Smith
Anna_Smith
Smith Anna
```

I above case i am able to figure out Anna Smith, Anna.smith and Anna_Smith are the same person. But i am unable to find any logic that can help me say that Smith Anna is same as Anna Smith.

Currently using MS-SQl
below is the logic

```
select name, isnull(lower(dbo.RemoveSpecialChars(substring(name, 0,      charindex('@',name)))),dbo.RemoveSpecialChars(name)) nospacename
   into #sheet32
   from [dbo].['Sheet3 (2)$']
```

I am removing all the characters like

> ".", ";"," "

that occurs within the names and concatenating them as one name
Therefore Anna Smith, Anna.Smith, Anna_Smith will all be converted to AnnaSmith. RemoveSpecialChars - is an user defined function

Is there any way i can figure out Anna Smith and Smith Anna are the same names? Currently working on MS-SQl. Solutions given in Excel, C# and VBA is also fine.

Thanks,
Sachi

Comment: I suppose you could split the words, and call the names the same if the words are the same, regardless of order.  But how meaningful is that?  Some names could be either first or last; and  `George Alexander` might be a different person than `Alexander George`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ron mentioned, splitting the words might be a simple way of doing it. (This is in c#)

```
        //String you want to check
        string names = "Smith Anna";

        //Split
        char[] splitters = { '-', '_', '.',' '};
        List<string> result = names.Split(splitters).ToList();

        //Sort the list
        result.Sort();
```

and then just perform the comparison.

Comment: Thank you :)   Working on similar lines

Comment: @maverick Just a quick one, if you feel that your question was answered, you should mark an answer as accepted. That way, other users can see that your question was answered and that you are not awaiting further answers :) - otherwise feel free to supplement the answer or post your own if it might help others :)

Comment: Oh forgot to do that. Apologize :)